# Unable to check Request.IsAjaxRequest() inside my action filter class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following action filter class:-

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class CheckUserPermissionsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        Repository repository = new Repository();
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

string ADusername = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Substring(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
if (!repository.can(ADusername,Model,Action))            {
var viewResult = new ViewResult();
viewResult.ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/Unauthorized.cshtml";
filterContext.Result = viewResult;}
base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}}
```

But I need to return two views based on the request type, if it is Ajax or not  such as:-

```
    If (Request.IsAjaxRequest()){
    viewResult.ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/_PartialUnauthorized.cshtml";

    }
else{
    viewResult.ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/Unauthorized.cshtml";
```

but I can not reference Request inside the class ? can anyone advice please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I can not reference Request inside the class ?

You already did this in the first line of code inside the `OnActionExecuting` method.

You could retrieve it from the `filterContext` argument that is passed to your `OnActionExecuting` method:

```
bool isAjax = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
```